# Is it possible to get list of libraries set that produce fine build?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, raspberry-pi

Trying to build GCC for Raspberry Pi from source according to [project](https://github.com/pwaring/gcc-cross-compiler) in my Ubuntu 20.04 machine with gcc 9.3.0 . Getting different problems while taking different sets of libraries

Configuration below brings `__uint128_t` error:

```
GCC_VERSION="9.3.0"
BINUTILS_VERSION="2.34"
GLIBC_VERSION="2.31"
MPFR_VERSION="3.1.6"
MPC_VERSION="1.0.3"
GMP_VERSION="6.2.0"
CLOOG_VERSION="0.18.1"

In file included from ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/bits/sigcontext.h:30,
                 from ../signal/signal.h:291,
                 from ../include/signal.h:2,
                 from ../misc/sys/param.h:28,
                 from ../include/sys/param.h:1,
                 from ../sysdeps/generic/hp-timing-common.h:39,
                 from ../sysdeps/generic/hp-timing.h:25,
                 from ../nptl/descr.h:27,
                 from ../sysdeps/arm/nptl/tls.h:42,
                 from ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/tls.h:23,
                 from ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/sysdep.h:30,
                 from <stdin>:1:
/home/a/gcc_buildings/1/xc-arm-linux-gnueabi/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/asm/sigcontext.h:77:2: error: unknown type name ‘__uint128_t’
   77 |  __uint128_t vregs[32];
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Configurations below brings the same `mpfr_fmma` error:

```
GCC_VERSION="9.3.0"
BINUTILS_VERSION="2.34"
GLIBC_VERSION="2.31"
MPFR_VERSION="4.1.0"
MPC_VERSION="1.0.3"
GMP_VERSION="6.2.0"
CLOOG_VERSION="0.18.1"

GCC_VERSION=9.3.0"
MPFR_VERSION="4.1.0"
MPC_VERSION="1.2.1"
GMP_VERSION="6.2.1"
ISL_VERSION="0.18"
CLOOG_VERSION="0.18.1"

/home/a/gcc-cross-compiler/xc-arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/tmp/gcc-4.9.2/mpfr/src/mpfr.h:765:21: note: previous declaration of ‘mpfr_fmma’ was here
  765 | __MPFR_DECLSPEC int mpfr_fmma (mpfr_ptr, mpfr_srcptr, mpfr_srcptr, mpfr_srcptr,
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~
make[3]: *** [Makefile:532: mul.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/a/gcc-cross-compiler/xc-arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/tmp/build-gcc/mpc/src'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:462: all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/a/gcc-cross-compiler/xc-arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/tmp/build-gcc/mpc'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:373: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/a/gcc-cross-compiler/xc-arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/tmp/build-gcc/mpc'
make: *** [Makefile:5289: all-mpc] Error
```

In other libraries combinations I'm getting other errors.

Is it possible to get list of libraries set that produce fine build?

Comment: `Is it possible to get list of libraries set that produce fine build?` Try every combination and write up the results? I would recommend publishing the results as others may be interested.

Comment: the error you've posted is just a note about the error which is presumably on the lines above it.